# eventful API php

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to use the eventful API via php to retrieve events and then show them with js. I am using the following php code:

```
$response = http_get($uri, array("timeout"=>1), $info);
    echo json_encode($response);
```

where $uri is :

```
 $uri = "http://api.eventful.com/rest/events/rss?app_key={keyhere}&keywords=concerts&location=seattle&sort_order=date";
```

However I receive nothing when I read the response in my js script, any idea how to approach this? I cannot find any documentation for it.

Comment: Try `file_get_contents($uri)` instead. The [documentation](http://au2.php.net/http_get) for `http_get` says: *Returns the HTTP response(s) as string on success, or FALSE on failure.*.

Comment: still nothing, my js is 'function getEvents()
{
       $.ajax({
                        type:"post",
                        url:"assets/php/api.php",
                        datatype:'json',
                        data:{'action':'getEvents'},
                        success:function(data)
                        {
                            console.log(data);
                           
                        }
            });
}'